# Drawing graphic layer on client side with ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, jquery

I'm using ArcGIS API for JavaScript 2.8.

I have some problems with drawing graphics point on client side. The problem is, when I draw points by first time by JS api everything is OK. But when points exists and I try to realy fast pan my map window from left to right (for example) my graphic layer can't finish drawing before one pan is ended. After few this kind of operations I can see, that my graphics points aren't in the geographic position as they should be when I started to pan. My question is how can I block again pan untill my graphic is drawn properly. I think it is the only way to prevent described situation.
I would like to mention, that I'm using jQuery for this application and I tried many many tricks like setting flag and setting enableMapNaviagtion() after document ready, I have tried to setTimeout, but for now this doesnt works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that when I release mouse button, but still move mouse over the screen, the map was moving with me. (only in google chrome) but when I changed event from onPanStart/Stop to onMouseDragStart/Stop everything works good, but I had to check if pan tool is active.

Comment: Thanks for posting your solution. We had a similar problem with zooming in IE8 and your post helped us find a solution.